# Tweepy return tweets for a particuler screen name only if the user tweets a new tweet

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using python and Tweepy in a script that loops and prints the tweet id, the time it was created and the full text. The problem am having is that it keeps on printing the same id and full text if there is no new tweet, is it possible to have an if statement or a listener that will only print the id, time created and full text only once and wait until the user creates a new tweet.

Below is my code:

```
import tweepy
import tkinter
import time

CONSUMER_KEY= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
# set parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser() if you want a nice printed json response.

user = api.me()

while True:

    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = "elonmusk", 
                           count=1,
                           include_rts = False,
                           tweet_mode = 'extended'
                           )

    for detailsInTweet in tweets:

        print("ID: {}".format(detailsInTweet.id))
    
        # Tweet creation time
        print(detailsInTweet.created_at, "\n")

        # Full tweet text
        print(detailsInTweet.full_text, "\n")

        print("\n")

        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You want to use `tweepy.Stream()`

Comment: @JonSG yeah do you have the code for that